# OpenCV Text Block Detection

Tags: objective-c, opencv, text

I need to use OpenCV to detect all the text blocks in an image to prepare them to be sent to OCR.
From my limited knowledge of OpenCV here is one of my possible solutions, however I am not sure how to turn this into a real solution.

1. Use findContours to detect contours of characters
2. Filter characters using hierarchy
3. Put bounding rect on filtered area
4. Group bounding rects to contain the text blocks

Would this work? If so how do I "execute" this? The scan may have multiple blocks of text, I am doing this on iOS.

Will this work for something such as a business card? That may have blocks of text on each corner? I just need to scan the text and have the group/blocks scanned together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have recently used the following approach for extracting text blobs:

1. Detect keypoints using the MSER algorithm. I found that it is good for finding letters.
2. Optionally, filter out the "small" and "very large" ones (the size property).
3. Group the keypoints into groups of adjacent letters - adjacency defined by a heuristic that two keypoints must be of similar size and close together (distance relative to their size).
4. Take the bounding box of each group, this is a candidate word or character blob.
5. Send it to OCR (I had good results with the Tesseract OCR library).

The above worked fairly well for text on clean backgrounds, however if there is a lot of non-text artwork as well it did detect non-textual blobs since the only pre-OCR filtering is the "similar size and nearby" metric.

If you are scanning business cards, it will probably be good enough.

You will need to calibrate the "nearby" and similar size heuristics for your domain.

For "similar size" I used ratios of keypoint size between 3/5 and 5/3, and "nearby" defined as distance between the key points less than 7/4 times the size of the smallest keypoint of the two.

In natural images, you need a more robust approach. For this I can recommend the following paper:

[Robust Text Detection in Natural Images with MSER](http://www.stanford.edu/~hchen2/papers/ICIP2011_RobustTextDetection.pdf)

Comment: Thank you, do you have a project or example you wouldn't mind sharing with me?